# When will parallel execution in EOS be supported?

Tags: smart-contract

In the white paper, it says:

> To support parallel execution, each account can also define any number
>   of scopes within their database. The block producers will schedule
>   transaction in such a way that there is no conflict over memory access
>   to scopes and therefore they can be executed in parallel.

What is the plan from the dev team to support this feature? Is there a alpha/beta version to try it with?

Answer (score 1):

According to [BlockOne's roadmap](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/Roadmap.md#phase-4---parallel-optimization-summer--fall-2018):

> **Phase 4 - Parallel Optimization Summer / Fall 2018**
>
> After getting a stable 1.0 product released, we will move toward optimizing the code
>   for parallel execution.